# What is the advantage of using HttpContext over HttpApplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, page-lifecycle

What is the advantage of intercepting a request for an ASP.Net application at the HttpContext level rather than waiting for the request to be processed by the HttpApplication pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing apples to oranges.  The HTTPContext holds the HTTP-specific information about an **individual** HTTP request while an HTTPApplication contains events that process that request.

Perhaps you are referring to HTTPHandlers and HTTPModules?  In other words you would intercept a request using an HTTPHandler referencing the HTTPContext to get information about that request like the query string etc...

Comment: Ah ha! When you said "you would intercept a request using an HTTPHandler referencing the HTTPContext to get information about that request like the query string etc" actually jived with what another developer and I have had a conversation about. While the code we're looking at isn't an advantage over HttpApplication, it's accessing a totally different area with different information. Thanks for the second opinion on this!

Answer (score 2):

This may help you in understanding the concepts

[HttpContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx)

[HttpApplication Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx)

Thanks